# how to whether item refunded or not through invoice level in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, invoice

I want to know whether a specific item is refunded or not from invoice level.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/orders/order-issue-refund.html